# What iterate method does protobuf-net used when serialize/deserialize an enumerable instance?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Enumerable instance may be from List, Dictionary, ConcurrentDictionary or my own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a surprisingly complex question. When *serializing*, it *mostly* just uses `foreach`, i.e. the `GetEnumerator()` API - or flat indexer-based enumeration for arrays. When *deserializing* it *mostly* tries to look for a `.Add(YourType t)` method. For dictionaries, it'll look for any of `Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)`, `Add(TKey, TValue)`, or the indexer `TValue this[TKey]` (for "maps" in particular).

However! Reality is much more nuanced than this, as we also need to think about a range of more complex collection types. For 2.4.* this is *very* hard to grok, because it is all runtime IL, however: for the 3.0 branch you can see some of the scenarios [here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/tree/master/src/protobuf-net.Core/Serializers) - in particular, see:

- RepeatedSerializer.cs
- RepeatedSerializer.Immutable.cs
- RepeatedSerializer.Concurrent.cs
- MapSerializer.cs
- MapSerializer.Immutable.cs
- MapSerializer.Concurrent.cs

*Usually*, however: the answer is: "it'll just work".

Comment: Collection modification may happen when serializing, and an exception throwed. Which collection type can use without exception? Does 2.4.* version support Immutable* types?

Comment: @JeffreyHill "Collection modification may happen when serializing, and an exception throwed." - do you have a concrete example, so we can discuss it in context? it is very unusual for that to happen when serializing. "Which collection type can use without exception?" - would need more info on the exception you're seeing. " Does 2.4.* version support Immutable* types?" - in principle yes, but the support is better in 3.*; let me know if you're seeing a problem!

Comment: exception throwed because serialized object is not thread-safe.

Comment: @JeffreyHill most objects aren't; if you're serializing a non-thread-safe object you *really shouldn't be poking it* from other threads, but that's true of *just about any code* that works this way, and is not specific to serialization; this feels like an X/Y problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class with a plain `IEnumerable` property, like so:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
class Dummy
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when protobuf-net deserializes the object, the actual underlying object will be a `List<T>` - in this case, a `List<string>`.

For serializing, if you set it to some completely custom enumerable implementation, protobuf-net simply iterates through it as per normal and serializes each value.